# Android: the soft keyboard is hiding the EditText in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I have a fragment that has some EditTexts that need to be filled by the user. There's a problem that the soft keyboard hides the EditText so that the user cannot see what they're writing. I don't want the user to scroll manually, I want the fragment to adjust so that it fits the keyboard automatically.
IMPORTANT NOTE: I have seen lots of suggestions to add `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`
or `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`in manifest. However, I want this action to be only for a specific fragment and not for all fragments within the activity.
I have tried adding `requireActivity().window.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE)`
In `onCreateView` or in `onCreate` but nothing seems to change.

Comment: have you tried this -->`getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE)` inside  `onActivityCreated`   ????

Comment: can you post up dependency that you used for material `com.google.android.material:material` ?? what version you are using?

Comment: @Wini it's 1.3.0

Comment: in my case...i have just defined in manifest `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` for the activity(where my fragment lies) and it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

In my case,
`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` and `ScrollView`

it's work for Fragment in Activity.